# Accessing struct elements/methods using embedded mono

Tags: frida, mono-embedding

I am working with a mono environment using the mono embedded methods (Frida).

There is a variable from which I know it contains a [System.Guid](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/main/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/guid.cs#L21) - unfortunately this is a pretty complex `struct` and not a `class` type so all functions like `mono_object_get_class` don't work:

```
public partial struct Guid : IFormattable, IComparable
...
```

I tried to unbox the struct using `mono_object_unbox` but that also fails.

How to access the fields or the methods of such a struct?

All I try is e.g. calling it's `ToString()` method to get a useful representation of the Guid data.